# Best use of port 80 for my Tor relay

Tags: relays

My relay is currently using the default ports (9001, 9030). I'm using port 443, but 80 is available. Would it be useful to use port 80 for either the ORPort or the DirPort? If so, which one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but my gut feeling is...
If you're a Guard, then ORPort, otherwise either DirPort or "doesn't matter".

It makes sense to help clients connect to you from behind a firewall. Other relays not so much. If you run a relay, you know you do so publicly, and probably not from a restricted place. Relays are likely able to connect to you on any port.

Comment: I'm not a Guard, so I think I'll go for the DirPort. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @MBE if this post helped you, please mark it as the answer to your question ;)